# How to make Shibboleth IdP send an attribute in emailAddress format?

Tags: shibboleth

I am trying to configure a Shibboleth identity provider to work with an existing SAML 2.0 service provider (I assume it's also Shibboleth), but it fails with an InvalidNameIDPolicy status and the following error message.

```
Required NameID format not supported
```

The AuthnRequest message has the following restriction.

```
<samlp:NameIDPolicy 
    AllowCreate="true" 
    Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:emailAddress"/>
```

How do I create an attribute of the desired type?  How would I change the following attribute definition in attribute-resolver.xml to have the right format?

```
<resolver:AttributeDefinition xsi:type="ad:Simple" id="email" 
                              sourceAttributeID="EMAIL">
    <resolver:Dependency ref="myRef" />
    <resolver:AttributeEncoder xsi:type="enc:SAML1String" 
                               name="urn:mace:dir:attribute-def:mail"/> 
    <resolver:AttributeEncoder 
         xsi:type="enc:SAML2String" 
         name="urn:oid:0.9.2342.19200300.100.1.3" friendlyName="mail"/> 
</resolver:AttributeDefinition>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is to add the following AttributeEncoder at the beginning of the list.

```
<resolver:AttributeEncoder 
     xsi:type="enc:SAML2StringNameID"
     nameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:emailAddress" />
```